# Sharepoint 2016 on-premise with ADFS - cannot open an office document in desktop app, credentials not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, office, adfs

I have a setup made-up of 2 machines:

- one Windows Server 2012 with Sharepoint 2016 (and other additional features like DNS, ADFS, ADDS, ADCS, etc.)
- one "client machine" used to access the Sharepoint, also with Office 2016 installed.

The Sharepoint is configured to use an ADFS Trusted Identity provider, and Windows Authentication is disabled. **Logging-in to Sharepoint with users from that domain works fine.** (eg. username@domain.name)

***THE PROBLEM:*** I click an Office document in Sharepoint (eg. sample.docx), I use the "Open in Word" feature, the Word app opens and prompts for SharePoint credentials in order to open the file. **The same credentials that I use to browse the SharePoint form a browser, do not work in Word.** (same problemf or excel, powerpoint, etc...) I tried various syntax forms (username@domain.name, DOMAIN.NAME\username), but it made no difference.

Any ideas to fix this ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try to provide only username without domain ..

Comment: I haven't included ALL examples, but I did try that one as well, not working.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix to this issue *by accident* after a while: try to open documents (in Word, Excel, Powerpoint...) ***from Internet explorer first***.

In this case, authentication works fine. Furthermore, after this step, documents can be properly opened in correct apps from other browsers as well (tested Chrome and Firefox).

Most likely there is a Sharepoint-related bug in the way the initial authentication token is passed to the desktop app, making this process to only work correct in Internet Explorer.